# How to convert image to bitmap code for bluetooth print in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata

I am interested to print image from iPhone programmatically using bluetooth printer device.

In one of the sample code I have implemented code for Text print but in that sample I am not getting how to convert image into format, like

```
        unsigned char buffer3[796]={
        0x55 ,  0x66 ,  0x77 ,  0x88 ,  0x44 ,  0x1B ,  0x58 ,  0x31 ,  
        0x19, 0x20, 
        0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0x60 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03
        ,0xA0 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0xB0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x05 ,0x60 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0xD8 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x05 ,0xA0 ,0x00 ,0x13 ,0xEC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x04 
        ,0x20 ,0x00 ,0x29 ,0xF4 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x64 ,0xF9 ,0x00
        ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0x7F ,0xF9 ,0xC0 ,0x3D ,0xFF
        ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF2 ,0x73 ,0x80 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0
        ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0x7F ,0xFD ,0xE0 ,0x3D ,0xFF ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x79 ,0x26 ,0xC0 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE
        ,0xFF ,0xFD ,0xF0 ,0x7D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0xFF ,0xF7 ,0xFF ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0x3C ,0x8F ,0x60
        ,0x0C ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF0 ,0x7D ,0x80
        ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x04 ,0x9E ,0x8F ,0xB0 ,0x0E ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0
        ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF8 ,0xFD ,0x80 ,0x33 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0
        ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0x4F ,0x27 ,0xD8 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC 
        ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xF9 ,0xFD ,0xFF ,0xF3 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0x26 ,0x53 ,0xC8
        ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9C ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0xEF ,0xFD ,0xDD ,0xDD ,0xFF
        ,0xF3 ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0x90 ,0xC9 ,0xF0 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0
        ,0x19 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0xEF ,0xFD ,0xDF ,0x9D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0
        ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xC9 ,0xE4 ,0xE0 ,0x0C ,0x00 ,0xDC ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x06 
        ,0xE7 ,0xFD ,0xCF ,0x9D ,0x80 ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xF0 ,0xF2 ,0x40
        ,0x0E ,0x01 ,0xDC ,0x00 ,0xC0 ,0x19 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xCF ,0x1D ,0x80
        ,0x3B ,0x80 ,0x77 ,0x00 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xE6 ,0x79 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0xDF ,0xFC ,0xFF
        ,0xF9 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC7 ,0x1D ,0xFF ,0xFB ,0xFF ,0xF7 ,0xFF ,0xE0
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x49 ,0x3D ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x9F ,0xFC ,0xFF ,0xF9 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFE
        ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC2 ,0x1D ,0xFF ,0xF1 ,0xFF ,0xE3 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1C ,0x9E ,0x00 
        ,0x0F ,0xFF ,0x1F ,0xFC ,0x7F ,0xE1 ,0xFF ,0xC0 ,0x7F ,0xFC ,0xE0 ,0x1D ,0xC0 ,0x1D ,0xFF
        ,0xE0 ,0xFF ,0xC1 ,0xFF ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0x4C ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0F ,0x20 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x07 ,0x90 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x03 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
        ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00   
    };


    //[self addLabel:@"buffer3 is selected"];
    [[session outputStream] write:(const uint8_t *)buffer3 maxLength:796];//send print package*/
```

This is sample code for Image print I am not able to print any other image because I am not having idea how to convert UIImage or NSData to the below mentioned Bit code. If any proper step by step method to do Image to bitmap conversion, then please let me know this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at this question, which is basically the same as the one I have and what you are asking: [How do I convert a hex array into a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093143/how-do-i-convert-a-hex-array-into-a-uiimage)

Have a look at Developer guide for the p25 printer (the pdf is attached at the above link in the answer)
[Specifically struggle through p.20 - 24;p. 48 - 53 for some examples and p.56 for iPhone specific print commands which are seen in the sample code]
p.22 shows how the images are made up from pixels. I'm thinking in the line of converting a .png image to .bmp or some simple black and white image format, which I don't know yet. You can share if you have any success. The solutions that have been given in the other six questions exactly like yours, haven't help me solve the problem completely yet (though I haven't given up)

Good luck!

**Update**

Thus far I've managed to convert a .png image to a black and white image by setting the pixel values to black or white, depending on the average of the RGB values. My code is a combination of code from different posts, the links of which I haven't posted here.

Each pixel is represented by 4 bytes. Once I've changed the color value of pixel to black or white I only need to look at the first byte of every 4 pixels for the rest of my calculation. If its value is 0 (r, g, b are all == 0 and thus the color of the pixel is black) I store 2^7 in an **int** var **pixelCount**, which represents **10000000** in binary, thus 1 pixel according to the printer. I then I continue on to the next pixel, adding 2^6 (01000000 in binary) to **pixelCount** if the value of the first **char** for that group of 4 bytes is 0 (pixel is black). The 2^ values for 8 pixels are added and stored as a **unsigned char** which represents 8 pixels (1 byte). I have sent a buffer array of these char values to the printer, but it prints ASCII characters which might mean my print image command is typed incorrectly.

Any comments about my code would be appreciated. Hope this helps.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"label.png"];
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height*width*4, sizeof(unsigned char));
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel* width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
//this methid returns the pixel data in rawData
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                                             width,
                                             height,
                                             bitsPerComponent,
                                             bytesPerRow,
                                             colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0, width,height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);

size_t length = image.size.height*image.size.width*4;
CGFloat intensity;

//black or white
int bw;

//initialize print buffer
size_t bufferLength = (image.size.height*image.size.width) / 8+10;
unsigned char buffer[bufferLength];

buffer[0] = 0x55; buffer[1] = 0x66; buffer[2] = 0x77; buffer[3] = 0x88; //esc sequence
buffer[4] = 0x44; //print command
buffer[5] = 0x1B; buffer[6] = 0x58; buffer[7] = 0x31;buffer[8] = (char) 200/8 ; buffer[9] = 30 ;  //and iOS specific print image command

int pixelCount = 0;
int byteCount = 10;


//check pixel values and average to black or white (4 bytes per pixel)
for(int index = 0; index<length;index+=4){
    intensity = (float)(rawData[index]+rawData [index+1] + rawData[index+2])/3.;

    if(intensity >= 128 ){
        bw = 255;
        //if pixel white, bit is 0

    }
    else {
        bw = 0;
                    //if black pixel, set one bit of byte on
        buffer[byteCount] += (char) pow(2, 7 - pixelCount);

    }

    //next pixel
    pixelCount++;

    //every 8 pixels, move to next char of print buffer
    if(pixelCount % 8 == 0)
        byteCount++;



    //      NSLog(@"Pixel %i : r: %i g: %i b: %i a: %i", counter++, rawData[index], rawData[index+1], rawData[index+2], rawData[index+3]);

    //save pixel values as black or white for new image
    rawData[index]   = bw;
    rawData[index+1] = bw;
    rawData[index+2] = bw;
    rawData[index+3] = 255;
}


CGContextRef bitmapContext=CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, image.size.width, image.size.height, 8, 4*image.size.width, colorSpace,  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CFRelease(colorSpace);

free(rawData);
CGImageRef cgImage=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);

UIImage *bwImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
[imageView setImage:bwImage];


//          NSLog(@"2011printing imagelog");
//      //[self addLabel:@"buffer3 is selected"];
//      [[session outputStream] writ
```